# django- search for list box elements and palce the selected elements in another box

Tags: django, search, listbox

I want a search for my list box.The selected items should then be shifted into another box.The same functionality is provided by django admin where you add user permissions.Any idea how I can implement it in my app?

Thank u !!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to do it in the Admin, it's just a matter of declaring 'filter_horizontal'

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal